# How to send TextView content via SMS

Tags: java, android, mobile

I am trying to get the data from the TextView in the Fragment and send it using ACTION_SEND.  So far all I can do is send a literal/hardcoded string.

```
public void implicitSendQuote(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", "@string/quote_1");
    // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, R.id.textView1);
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

This is the MainActivity containing implicitSendQuote method

```
package org.example.androidsdk.demo;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    android.app.FragmentManager manager;
    ViewPager viewpager;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // instantiate TextView object
        //TextView textViiew = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        // initialize viewPager
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);

        // create object of Adapter class
        PagerAdapter padapter = new org.example.androidsdk.demo.PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(padapter);

        manager = getFragmentManager();
    }

    public void slideBack() {
        Fragment f1 = new Fragment();
        android.app.FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.pager, f1, "X");

        // addToBackStack here
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);

        transaction.commit();
    }



    public void implicitSendQuote(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra("sms_body", "TEXT");
        // intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, R.id.textView1);
        intent.setType("*/*");
        startActivity(intent);
    }


}
```

This is the XML Layout for the given Activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#F20C36" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="62dp"
        android:text="@string/quote_1"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="132dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="108dp"
        android:text="Share" 
        android:onClick="implicitSendQuote"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what do you have problems with?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html#String

Comment: any luck in getting text?

Comment: Nope...  I have a problem with this line:  String text = textview.getText().toString();    The getText method is not available, only getTextColor(s).

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `R.id.textView1` for getting TextView content.

```
//inside onCreate
TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

// your method to send SMS
public void implicitSendQuote(View v) {
    //get TextView content
    String text = textview.getText().toString();

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);  //use that String text over here.
    intent.setType("*/*");
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Hope this helps, and you get a clear picture of how to get text from views.

**EDIT**

In your code you have this commented line:

```
//TextView textViiew = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
```

Uncomment that. And use

```
String text = textViiew.getText().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", text);  //use that String text over here.
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

in your method `implicitSendQuote`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried this...  On the fourth line (intent.putExtra("sms_body", TextView.getText().toString());) I could not find the getText() method.  All I see related is getTextColor() and getTextColors().

Comment: @CodeRo update your question with code and xml please.

Comment: I uncommented textView in onCreate().  textView cannot be resolved:

Comment: @CodeRo You must be making some other mistake. Have you imported TextView? and clean build project once.

Comment: import android.widget.TextView;

Comment: Read [Simple android TextView tutorial](http://techtopz.in/2013/11/11/android-textview-tutorial-and-example/) @CodeRo you must be making some minor mistake.

Answer (score 0):

do this way:

```
public void implicitSendQuote(View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.putExtra("sms_body", TextView.getText().toString(););
// intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, R.id.textView1);
intent.setType("*/*");
startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: I tried this...  On the fourth line (intent.putExtra("sms_body", TextView.getText().toString());) I could not find the getText() method.  All I see related is getTextColor() and getTextColors().

Answer (score 0):

Try this code...

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "This is my text to send.");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(sendIntent);
```